# Kibana shows a blank dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to make Elasticsearch+Kibana work. For some reason I get a blank Kibana dashboard:
[image]

My config.js is a default file with only one line changed:

```
elasticsearch: "http://127.0.0.1:9200",
```

Elasticsearch is working correctly, `http://127.0.0.1:9200` returns this json:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Ikthalon",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "f1585f096d3f3985e73456debdc1a0745f512bbc",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-04-16T14:27:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.7"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But why is my Kibana dashboard blank? Maybe this is because I run it with URL `file:///home/sergey/Desktop/kibana-3.1.1/index.html#/dashboard/file/default.json`? If so, how do I make it work?

Comment: Why using that "file://" format? Why not `http://localhost:9292`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run kibana over a server. If you have python installed you can use

```
cd /path/to/kibana
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Or if you can put kibana source code in following directories if you are using Apache:

LAMP: /var/www

WAMP: C:/wamp/www

Answer (score 2):

You could open the same file from Firefox and Kibana would work.

Chrome blocks it as a security feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Logstash, there is an option to run Kibana embedded in Logstash. See `-a and -p flags` here http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/flags

Answer (score 1):

Javascript errors may be occured.In firefox i had 2 errors. fontawesome-webfont.woff and logstash.json files couldnt be found.I added iis MIME Types for .woff and .json. And then problem resolved.